# Sendgrid Next.js - React.js and Express.js - problem getting data

Tags: express, next.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

in my site Sendgrid is well configured and the Bearer token works fine and emails are being sent properly.

However I cannot get the lists.

If I use Postman to test the API https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/lists and I put only my token in the authorization, it works well and I can see all the lists.

However for some reason the data is not being downloaded from the server.js file.

```
server.get('/api/admin/lists', async (req, res) => {
    var response = await axios.get("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/marketing/lists", {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": process.env.SENDGRID_AUTH_TOKEN
        }
    });

    res.json(response.data.result);
})
```

And I am trying to download it from the component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchLists();
    console.log("thisssss", this.state)
}

fetchLists() {
    axios.get("/api/admin/lists")
        .then((x) => {
            this.setState(s => ({
                ...s,
                lists: x
            }));
        });
}
```

In the state the array is emopty:

```
lists: Array(0)
length: 0
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

And of course it says that map is not a function:

```
            <div className="row">
                <ul>
                {this.state.lists.map(x => {
                    <li>#{x.id} {x.name} (number of subscribed users: {x.contact_count}). 
  </li>
                })}
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Anybody knows what may be wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens if you log `response.data.result` on your server? Or should you wrap the call to the API in a `try/catch` to see if there are any errors?

Comment: When I add `console.log("LOGGING", response.data.result)` inside the `server.get`  block, in the terminal I see it returns an array with both lists. So it's working fine in the server side. It looks like then, the issue is in the component. For some reason the component is not able to fetch the data from the server.js ... any idea?

Comment: When using `axios`, the response data is available in the `data` field. Try passing `lists: x.data` instead.

Comment: you're right if I `console.log("X", x);` inside the `then` I see that the lists are in `data`.  However `then((x) => {
        this.setState((s) => ({
          ...s,
          lists: x.data,
        }));
      })` is still not saving data to the state. `The console.log` in `ComponentDidMount` is showing still an empty array for `lists`

Comment: Is an error thrown when you set the state?

Comment: no error at all in the console